# Gitlab потребляет всю память на VPS

Tags: ubuntu, memory, gitlab, ram

Здравствуйте, я поставил Gitlab на VPS. Сам Gitlab работает нормально, но потребляет все 4 гб оперативки, если ставлю gitlab-runner стразу всё виснет. Попробовал сократить кол-во процессов sidekiq c 25 до 10, память потребляется так же. Это так должно быть?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Есть подозрение, что да, правда у меня он два гига кушал